# How to copy a sub directory of one directory to another?

Tags: rsync, cp

How can I copy a directory structure named function under Dept2 directory into Dept3 directory in one shot?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-r` option to `cp` (or `-a` if you want to preserve all attributes):

```
cd Dept2; cp -r function /path/to/Dept3/
```

(this assumes that with one shot you mean a oneliner).

If `Dept2` and `Dept3` are under the same parent direcotry you can also do

```
cd Dept2; cp -r function ../Dept3
```

which is somewhat shorter